# Using rm -i !(*.c|Makefile) in Makefile?

Tags: c, linux, bash, makefile

I have a directory where I have some C program files and a Makefile with executables of those C files. I can simply run this to remove all the executable at once in `rm !(*.c|Makefile)`.

But when i am adding this to my makefile

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -g -lm

SHELL=/bin/bash
careful:
    echo "nothing"
clean:
    rm -i !(*.c|Makefile)
```

I am getting this error while executing the command

```sh
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: -c: line 1: `rm -i !(*.c|Makefile)'
make: *** [Makefile:8: clean] Error 2
```

I am not too knowledgeable about Bash syntax but I know that `()` is treated as a subshell, I think that's why I can't run `rm (*.c)` directly in the terminal because `*.c` is not a command (or any valid syntax). But running `rm -i !(*.c)` works in the terminal. So I guess `!()` is treated differently in Bash.

**My assumption on all this:** in Makefile when I am running `make clean` it is treating !(*.c|Makefile), differently  than in normal terminal, or somehow it is disregarding `!` in `!(*.c|Makefile)`

So my questions are:

1. Are `!()` and `()` treated differently in Bash?
2. Why does `!(wildcard)` work in the terminal but not in my `Makefile`
3. How can I make it work in the `Makefile`?

Comment: Just to note, source-control systems take care of this for you. In Git, for example, you'd run `git clean` to remove untracked files (which are probably anything other than your C files and your Makefile).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bash-specific extended globbing patterns are not enabled out of the box for noninteractive shells.

`!(...)` is purely part of this wildcard syntax, and has nothing with subshells to do.

Probably a better solution anyway is to refactor this so you don't depend on Bash.

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -i $(filter-out $(wildcard *.c) Makefile,$(wildcard *))
```

The Bash Reference Manual doesn't have a good anchor to link to, but the extended globbing syntax available with `extglob` is described in the section on [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching)

If you really wanted to, you could `shopt -s extglob` in your `Makefile`, too, but this gets rather complicated as you will have to hide the statement from the parser until the shell is configured to understand this syntax. For example,

```
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    shopt -s extglob; \
    eval 'rm -i !(*.c|Makefile)'
```

Notice also how `shopt` and `eval` need to be on the same logical line, as `make` out of the box executes each recipe line in a separate new shell instance (though you can change that with `.ONESHELL`)

Comment: Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you can't directly copy/paste this snippet into a Makefile.

Comment: So it means globbing patterns are not going to work for scripts too. and if this is so how one can enable globbing in non-interactive shells

Comment: and does `shopt -s extglob` only gets enable for interactive shells

Comment: It depends on how you have configured Bash. Probably you have this statement in one of the startup files which is only executed when you run an interactive shell, or a login shell. If you want to execute `shopt -s extglob` in your `Makefile`, you can obviously do that; but I would generally recommend against this when GNU `make` itself has adequate facilities for doing the same thing portably.

Comment: In general it's best to just not try to rely on super-fancy shell facilities and instead just write out the rule using simple operations as close to POSIX sh syntax as possible.  Also I would strongly discourage you from writing a rule that deletes "everything except XYZ" because someday you'll put an important file there that doesn't match "XYZ" and oops, there it goes.  **Much** safer to list the files you DO want to delete.

Comment: Extended globs are disabled by default for *all* shells, interactive or not. (They *are* enabled by default inside the `[[...]]` command, since compatibility with POSIX syntax is already out the window there.)

Comment: @chepner My impression is that some platforms now enable this feature for interactive shells, but of course I could not quickly find any documentation to corroborate that.

Comment: That's little to do with `bash`, and mostly to do with what configuration files the distribution supplies.

Comment: Sure, but I don't think the OP knows or cares whether that's the case here.